# Particle different in Render and Viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, particles

I have a particle system that looks different in the unbaked, as well as baked state in the viewport than in the render, in the viewport everything looks normal, in the render suddenly some particles are missing or hanging in space where there would be none in the viewport.[[image: In viewport it behaves normally]][1[image: ]]

Comment: yes, still the same

Comment: The problem is also inconsistent, I bake it with slightly different settings and it then suddenly shows the correct particles but not all in the render.

Comment: I have found a workaround, if I bake the particles and deactivate dead under Extras, then it does not show me particles in the render, but if I then activate dead again, the missing particles become visible.
As an addition, if I activate dead and then bake, I see too many particles in the render, logically, but if I then switch off dead, too many particles disappear again.
At least I have found a workaround.